# ReferenceError: err is not defined mongoose mongodb

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling

When I run this code, it returns an error saying that err is not defined

here is my code

```
app.post('/tinder/cards', (req, res) => {
const dbCard = req.body;

Cards.create(dbCard, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
        res.status(201).send(data);
    }
});

app.get('/tinder/cards', (req, res) => {
Cards.find(err, data => {
    if (err) {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    } else {
        res.status(200).send(data);
    }
});
```

Here is my definition of the MongoDB schema:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const cardSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    imgUrl: String,
});


export default mongoose.model('cards', cardSchema);
```

Someone, please help me fix this thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Cards.find(err, data =>
```

here it's looking for the filter/query as the 1st Parameter which `err` variable which is not defined so you're getting the ReferenceError.

To

```
Cards.find(query, (err, data) => { // 1st Parameter should be filter/query
```

---

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find

```
Model.find()
```

Parameters

```
filter «Object|ObjectId»
[projection] «Object|String|Array<String>» optional fields to return, see Query.prototype.select()
[options] «Object» optional see Query.prototype.setOptions()
[callback] «Function»
```

Comment: so would i just replace (err, data) with model.find() ?

Comment: Noooooooooooo , change to line above that.

Comment: so do i just copy paste that line of code that you said to change?

Comment: `Cards.find({}, (err, data) => {` also read --> https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.find